# Difficulty with recursive boolean method

Tags: java, recursion, methods, boolean

I'm trying to solve the sailors, monkey and coconuts problem by using a recursive algorithm. I want my program to state true or false if it is possible to solve the problem with the values given. In short, the problem is there are s sailors that are stranded on an island with a monkey and y coconuts. Throughout the night, one sailor will wake up, take the y coconuts and sort into s even piles, with one coconut left for the monkey. The sailor then buries one of the piles, and puts the other two piles back together. The next sailor wakes up, and does the same (creates s even piles with one left for the monkey, buries one of the piles, and puts back the other piles).

I also know that 2 sailors requires 7 coconuts, 3 sailors require 79 coconuts and 4 sailors require 1021 coconuts.

I'm having difficulty with my base cases. If I have a case where I have 4 sailors and 81 coconuts for example, my program will say it's possible since 4%81=1. However once the second sailor goes to sort the coconuts in this example, there aren't enough to sort.

Any help or suggestions would be greatly appreciated. Thank you so much!

```
public class test2 {

        public static void main(String[] args) {
            int sailors=4, sailorsRemaining=sailors, coconuts=81;
            testCoconuts(sailors, sailorsRemaining, coconuts);

         }//end main method

       public static boolean testCoconuts(int sailors, int sailorsRemaining, int coconutsRemaining){
            int s = sailors;
            int sr = sailorsRemaining;
            int cr = coconutsRemaining;

            if (cr%s==1 && sr==0) { //if there are enough coconuts to sort, but no sailors
              System.out.println("false1");
              return false;
           }

           else if (cr%s==1 && sr!=0) { //if there are enough coconuts and enough sailors to sort
            System.out.print("true1");
            return true;
          }

        if (cr%s!=1) { //if there are not enough coconuts to sort
            System.out.println("false2");
            return false;
        }
       else return testCoconuts(s, cr - ((cr-1)/s)-1, sr-1); //recursive step
    }

}//end class
```

Comment: I don't get why that first sailor will have 1 pile to bury and then have 2 piles to combine.  I thought there were suppose to be s piles.

Comment: And does the monkey get 1 coconut or 1 pile?

Comment: I suggest using a debugger or adding `System.out.println()` statements to debug your code.

Answer (score 0):

Your method takes in (sailors, sailors remaining, coconut count) but your return method sends (sailors, coconut count, sailors remaining).  You swapped the order.  That still didn't fix it though.  I rewrote the if statements and now it works, I think.  I did it by answering the following:

1. What criteria must be met if I can stop recursing and return true?
2. What criteria must be met if I can continue recursing?.

Answer these 2 and it should be a breeze to complete.  And debugging was key to solving it for me.

Answer (score 0):

This problem is somewhat related to number theory. For any number of sailors there is an infinite number of solutions.  The idea is to find the smallest one (number of coconuts).

The end result is a power series that results in one equation and two unknowns.  Fortunately it is easy to solve visually because the two large components are relatively prime to each other.  So the answer boils down to the following:

The smallest number of coconuts to satisfy the solution for **N** sailors is **N<sup>(N+1)</sup> - (N-1)**.

So for **3** coconuts **3<sup>4</sup> = 81 - 2 =79**

So all that is needed is a single method to calculate that value and return true or false appropriately.

```
// all the following print true;
System.out.println(check(7,2));
System.out.println(check(79,3));
System.out.println(check(15621,5));
    
    
public static boolean check(int coconuts, int sailors) {
    return (int)Math.pow(sailors, sailors+1) - (sailors - 1) == coconuts;
}
```

Note that there is variation of this problem where when the sailors all get together to do the final division, there is no remainder (i.e. the monkey doesn't get one).  In this case the solution is **N<sup>N</sup> - (N-1)**.